# Why does the File Geodatabase that I created not appear to any other users on the network?

Tags: arcmap, esri-geodatabase

I created a File Geodatabase to store files that I use in maps for my coworkers.  The folder is in a location where all users should have access and permissions.

Strangely enough, after I created the gdb, I'm the only one that can see or access it.  It appears in my Catalog view, but not in windows explorer. The map document that accesses the fcs in the gdb works fine for me but shows broken links for my colleagues. Any reason why this might be happening??

[image: Where's my database?]

Comment: have you checked only Fgdb is not visible to others ? could you try to create a notepad and check...

Comment: There is already a read-me file as well as two other directories in this particular folder.  Only the fgdb is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing that I would try is moving or copying the File GDB temporarily to a directory that does not contain any spaces or parentheses in the path.  These two items have caused many problems for people over the years.  Another issue may be the length of total file path, though by the looks of it, that would be the same for you as for them.

In general, a good rule of thumb is to try to keep the file name as short as possible, as well as the directory path as short as possible and free of special characters.  Where possible, it is better to use the underscore (_) instead of a dash (-)

Actually, looking at your picture, I see another item that is concerning.

On the left, the directory you are pointing at:
Prop-540 Geographical Information System (GIS) Data files

Contains two directories:
Coastal SP 2012
FloridaWindData

It does not contain your geodatabase

On the right, the directory only contains
DataForProjects.gdb

It does not show the other two directories.

Is there any way that they could actually be pointing to two different directories, even though it looks like the same one?  The only other thing I could guess, would be a permissions issue of some sort.

Comment: Thanks, I should have been tipped off by not having those other directories in there.  Both folders have the same file structure, but one has an extra \ES\ in it.  So the answer to my question of why can't I see the geodatabase in my folder is that it's not the right folder, how embarassing.

Comment: @roy, we've all been there! Not everyone has the wherewithal to admit it though :) So kudos to you for being up front about it.